# php mysql does not insert data

Tags: php, mysql

I try to write the get-methods to insert the data into the table. Actually, with one table everything goes well. Look at the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);

$db_host = "..."; 
$db_user = "...";
$db_password = "...";
$db_table = "Task"; 

$name = $_GET['Name'];
$groupId = $_GET['GroupId'];
$creatorId = $_GET['CreatorId'];
$comment = $_GET['Comment'];

$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) OR DIE("DB connection fail...");
mysql_select_db("...", $db);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db);

$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (Name, Group_ID, Creator_ID, Comment) VALUES ('$name', '$groupId', '$creatorId', '$comment')");
$id = mysql_insert_id();

header('Content-Type: application/json');


if ($result = 'true'){
    $response = array( 'result' => 'OK', 'id' => $id );
    //setcookie("TaskManagerUser", $id);
    echo json_encode($response);
} else{
    $response = array( 'result' => 'FAIL');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

BUT when i try to insert into another table "Group", nothing happens. id is always 0 in mysql_insert_id();
Primary keys in both tables are AU and unique

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);

$db_host = "..."; 
$db_user = "...";
$db_password = "...";
$db_table = "Group"; 

$name = $_GET['Name'];

$db = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_password) OR DIE("DB connection fail...");
mysql_select_db("...", $db);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $db);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".$db_table." (Name) VALUES ('$name')");

$id = mysql_insert_id();

header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($result = 'true'){
    $response = array( 'result' => 'OK', 'id' => $id );
    //setcookie("TaskManagerUser", $id);
    echo json_encode($response);
} else{
    $response = array( 'result' => 'FAIL');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those, who decided to create a table with name "Group" - do not do this! That was the point. I changed its name and it worked!

Comment: You could also put the name in backticks. That's how you use names that are the same as reserved words.